# inaccurate mouse cursor in Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.1 in VM Fusion on Mac

Tags: mouse, touchpad, cursor

My cursor is significantly off where I think it should be, ie, if I want to copy text from Terminal, it will capture text one line down at least from where the cursor is. Resizing windows shows the resizer to be waay inside the window, not over the edge of app window (as expected). This is the same for the trackpad or Wacom tablet, which works just fine in all my other VMs and Mac apps. any suggestions?

Comment: Have you made sure that you installed the [VMware Tools](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1022048) for VMFusion?

Comment: They are installed by default. I suppose I can re-install them.. Will report back after